# Best practices for using Django ORM in threaded application

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a multi-threaded application that uses the Django ORM with MySQL. The idea is to use a single startup script to launch multiple modules ("module" here in the functional sense, not the literal Python sense), each of which has a "service loop" that runs in its own thread. I've organized it using a single class for each module.

I originally did this using a sqlite DB and it worked great. Now I'm transitioning to MySQL and am running into DB connection problems related to threading. For example, it looks like I need to call db.connections.close_all() within each thread to avoid contention with the DB connection? I'm thinking that I need to move all setup related to the Django ORM to the service thread but then I wouldn't be able to import models in the class's init() method.

Anyway, I'm sure that other people have dealt with this before, and I'm sure there are some good patterns out there. Anyone have any suggestions or best practices they could share?

This is my simple startup script:

```
from controller.modules.manager import Manager
from controller.modules.scanner import Scanner

print("Starting...")

# The directory scanner
scanner = Scanner()

# The job manager
manager = Manager()
```

And here's an example of one of the modules (the Scanner class):

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
import threading
import django

# Need to do this before importing models
from common.utilities.os import OS
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "common.settings"
django.setup()

# Import models here

class Scanner:
    def __init__(self):
        # Define some member variables here, some of which include
        # DB models

        # Launch service loop
        Process(target=self.service_loop, name='service loop').start()

    def service_loop(self):
        while True:
            # Scan some directories and update some DB entries

            # Throttle the loop
            sleep(config.THROTTLE_SLEEP_TIME_SEC)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED. After countless hours of experimenting and googling I finally found exactly what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912048/how-to-handle-mysql-connections-with-python-multithreading). I inherited the module classes from python's threading.Thread class and it solved all issues.